# Unexpected Nil when unwrapping String? makes app crashed

Tags: swift, null, interface-builder, nsdate, uistoryboard

My app has a screen that takes some inputs like `title: String?`, `desc: String?`, `dueDate: NSDate?`. If all inputs given, return back and pass data to previous screen via delegate/protocol, otherwise, block navigation and display pop-up warning.

This is the codes to validate inputs and perform navigation:

```
func pushView(sender: AnyObject) {
    if .........
    //Some codes to check inputs
    else {
        let aReminder = Reminders(title: self.remTitle.text!, dueDate: self.dueDate, desc: self.remDesc.text!)

        self.delegate!.addReminder(aReminder)

        //error drops on this line
        self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

The app checks empty inputs and shows warnings as intended but when I fill all textboxes and make change to datePicker, I got an error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

I have set a default value to `dueDate` by `var dueDate = NSDate()` but still got such error, while the text boxes are all filled out.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: In `pushView` in the `if` clause you check for **or** `|| dueDate == nil` that means that in the `else` clause `dueDate` could also be `nil` and causes the crash when unwrapping it. Easiest solution is to declare `dueDate` as non-optional with a default value of now`var dueDate = NSDate()`. But then you have to remove all the `nil` checking of the variable.

Comment: Yeh I have set a default value `var dueDate = NSDate()` and fix the code to run it. But the `nil` warning still appears.

Comment: The error is exactly on the line `self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: @LKPhucNguyen Then it means `self.navigationController` is `nil`. That means the controller is not inside a `UINavigationController`. Are you sure you don't want to dismiss your controller instead?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put a navigation controller in the `Main.StoryBoard`. So to fix the problem, I have fixed it like this:

- drag a `Navigation Controller` from Object Library into the Storyboard,
- Then Control + drag from the `Navigation Controller` to the current `View Controller`
- Select `Root View Controller` as the relationship of the two